# Is there a way to force a required file to be reloaded in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, require

Yes, I know I can just use `load` instead of `require`. But that is not a good solution for my use case:

When the app boots, it `requires` a config file. Each environment has its own config. The config sets constants.

When the app boots, only one environment is required. However, during testing, it loads config files multiple times to make sure there are no syntax errors.

In the testing environment, the same config file may be loaded more than once. But I don't want to change the `require` to load because every time the a spec runs, it reloads the config. This should be done via `require`, because if the config has already been loaded, it raises `already initialized constant` warnings.

The cleanest solution I can see is to manually reset the require flag for the config file after any config spec.

Is there a way to do that in Ruby?

Edit: adding code.

When the app boots it calls the init file:

```
init.rb:

require "./config/environments/#{ ENV[ 'RACK_ENV' ]}.rb"


config/environments/test.rb:

APP_SETTING = :foo


config/environments/production.rb:

APP_SETTING = :bar


spec/models/config.rb: # It's not a model spec...

describe 'Config' do
  specify do
    load './config/environments/test.rb'
  end

  specify do
    load './config/environments/production.rb'
  end
```

Comment: You do realise that the reason you are not getting "already initialized constant" from a `require` is *because* it skips loading the file. It is not any other property of `require` that prevents the warning - if you find a way to re-set the require flag then you *will* get the warnings about constants, exactly the same as using `load`.

Comment: Yes, I know. `Object.send :remove_const, const if Object.const_defined? const`

Comment: If you do that combined with `load`, does that solve your problem? If not, why not? The only objection to `load` I understand in your question is about the "already initialized constant" warnings - if there is another reason you cannot use `load` in your specs, I am not clear what that is?

Comment: Why not turn your configs into a Hash with the specified environment? eg. `CONFIGS[environment][some variable]` this should not have any noticeable performance impact since Hash access is very fast. Also this would allow you to build your config files in something like `YAML` for easy management.

Comment: @Neil Slater - One reason is that it pollutes the app code with spec code. Another reason is that unsetting a require flag would be more expressive.

Comment: @engineersmnky - Because it's not about performance and I don't like YAML. However, one solution would be to create a `Config` model to manage this. The problem is that I don't want to create a model used in the app for the convenience of the specs.

Comment: @BSeven: Maybe show the spec code (or a cut down version that demonstrates your problem)? I cannot see how adding `load` into the spec code would pollute the app code. I guess it may depend on what you are testing and how. But with Rspec and helpers it is rare to hit a complete barrier to unit tests. Are these unit tests?

Comment: `load` would go in the init for the app which is app code. These are mostly request specs. It is a Rack app.

Comment: @BSeven: You may have other design options for either the app or the specs that keep your main goal to have native Ruby config but that don't paint you into this corner. But they cannot be discussed without the code, and probably better discussed at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BSeven first of all just writing off something because you *"don't like"* it is very closed minded for someone asking a question. Secondly you do not need to implement this class in the app you could just create it to facilitate the specs themselves. Pleae keep in mind that you are asking others for help because the true answer to your overall problem is **No** (would you have preferred that as an answer?)

Comment: @engineersmnky - Didn't mean to sound closed minded. To the contrary, I am looking for new ideas. I think YAML is difficult to work with and error prone. How would you implement a class in the specs and not in the app? The constants are global. Regarding the answer, I had a sneaking suspicion that there is a way to do it because I saw a question about the "Global Constants table". I figured there should be a "Requires Table" as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done. You must know the path to the files that you want to reload. There is a special variable `$LOADED_FEATURES` which stores what has been loaded, and is used by `require` to decide whether to load a file when it is requested again.

Here I am assuming that the files you want to re-require all have the unique path `/myapp/config/` in their name. But hopefully you can see that this would work for any rule about the path name you can code.

```
$LOADED_FEATURES.reject! { |path| path =~ /\/myapp\/config\// }
```

And that's it . . .

Some caveats:

- `require` does not store or follow any kind of dependency tree, to know what it "should" have loaded. So you need to ensure the full chain of `require`s starting with the `require` command you run in the spec to re-load the config, and including everything you need to be loaded, is covered by the removed paths.
- This will not unload class definitions or constants, but simply re-load the files. In fact that is literally what `require` does, it just calls `load` internally. So all the warning messages about re-defining constants will also need to be handled by un-defining the constants you expect to see defined in the files.
- There is probably a design of your config and specs that avoids the need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to do this, here's one approach that doesn't leak into your test process. Fork a process for every config file you want to test, communicate the status back to the test process via `IO.pipe` and fail/succeed the test based on the result.

You can go as crazy as you want with the stuff you send down the pipe...

Here's some quick and dirty example to show you what I mean.

a config

```
# foo.rb
FOO = "from foo"
```

another config

```
# bar.rb
FOO = "from bar"
```

some faulty config

```
# witherror.rb
asdf
```

and your "test"

```
# yourtest.rb
def load_config(writer, config_file)
  fork do
    begin
      require_relative config_file
      writer.write "success: #{FOO}\n"

    rescue
      writer.write "fail: #{$!.message}\n"
    end
    writer.close
    exit # maybe this is even enough to NOT make it run your other tests...
  end
end

rd, writer = IO.pipe

load_config(writer, "foo.rb")
load_config(writer, "bar.rb")
load_config(writer, "witherror.rb")
writer.close

puts rd.read
puts rd.read
puts rd.read   
puts FOO
```

The output is:

```
success: from foo
success: from bar
fail: undefined local variable or method `asdf' for main:Object
yourtest.rb:24:in `<main>': uninitialized constant FOO (NameError)
```

as you can see, the FOO constant doesn't leak into your test process etc.
Of course you're only through half way because there's more to it like, making sure only one process runs the test etc.

Frankly, I don't think this is a good idea, no matter what approach you chose because you'll open a can of worms and imho there's no really clean way to do this.

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. It seems to be a good way to isolate the config in the test environment, without polluting the app code.